# Calling Oracle Stored Procedure using StoredProcedure provided by Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I see a code which seems to invoke a stored procedure using execute method in the class org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure. A map is passed as input to this method. However I don't see the stored procedure name or the function name  being passed as passed as input. How does Spring ensure the correct function within the stored procedure is executed?

```
    map.put(FAULT_CODE, faultCode);
    map.put(FAULT_MESSAGE, faultMessage);
    Map result = this.execute(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure` has 3 constructors:

For bean

```
protected StoredProcedure()
Allow use as a bean.
```

For use with data source:

```
protected StoredProcedure(DataSource ds,
                          String name)

//name - name of the stored procedure in the database
```

For create wrapper:

```
protected StoredProcedure(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate,
                          String name)
//name - name of the stored procedure in the database
```

In second and third case you specify name of stored procedure on creation. I suppose one of it its your case.